# Having trouble symmetrizing

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, mirror

I'm trying to symmetrize an object (in this case an airplane as I'm following a beginner tutorial) and am having some difficulty.

As instructed, I'm in edit mode, clicked the "A" key to select all, then went to "Mesh" > "Symmetrize"

When selected it looks like this, just like in the tutorial

[image]

However, when I hit "Symmetrize" this happens, instead of adding another wing on the other side as intended.

[image]

I notice it logged an error regarding the symmetrizing on the bottom

[image]

From a bit of Googling I tried the "Snap To Symmetry" option right under "Symmetrize" in the "Mesh" menu.

[image]

I changed the direction, threshold and factor a few times but nothing seemed to work. I'm assuming -X to +X is what I want since that's the red line.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Change it to (+X to -X) instead of (-X to +X)

Comment: That was actually it! I had tried that (as mentioned in the question) but for some reason the first few times it didn't do anything. Maybe the direction variable needed to be set somehow before clicking "symmetrize" again. I played with it for a bit and got it to work.